# Printing value_counts() and s.sum() on series throws syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am running this code:

```
s = pd.Series([random.randint(0, 20) for x in range(0, 10)], index=list(
        "ABCDEFGHIJ"))
print(s.quantile([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9])
print(s.value_counts())
print(s.sum())
```

and I keep getting this syntax error:

```
print(s.value_counts())
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please could you explain why it keeps throwing this error.

Comment: The code is working for me. Can you please copy these three lines into a text file, add the import statements for `pandas as pd` and `random` and check if you can run this file?

Comment: Code is working for me as well.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Yes the file is working when copied into another file. Thanks for your help. I stupidly forgot to paste the preceding print call where I missed a parenthesis!

Answer (score 0):

I am running the same code with the respective imports as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

s = pd.Series([random.randint(0, 20) for x in range(0, 10)], index=list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
print(s.value_counts())
print(s.sum())
```

and the results:

```
11    2
8     1
7     1
6     1
5     1
19    1
2     1
17    1
0     1
dtype: int64
86
```

and as you can see, there is no syntax error. Can you provide more information about what kind of dataset you're trying to create? are you importing the numpy.random module?

Answer (score 0):

i complied the same code it works fine for me

```
s = pd.Series([random.randint(0, 20) for x in range(0, 10)], index=list(
        "ABCDEFGHIJ"))
print(s.value_counts())
print(s.sum())
```

results:

```
14    2
8     2
12    1
10    1
7     1
6     1
19    1
1     1
dtype: int64
99
```

once make sure that s is properly initialized before before print statement is executed

Answer (score -1):

Just use `print(s.value_counts().sum())` or `s.value_counts`

But the results are different
when you use `s.value_counts`, it will print the index values
and `s.value_counts().sum()`, the total rows of the dataframe

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic mistake. You have "`"ABCDEFGHIJ"))`" on a new line, what you should do is keep it on the same line. This is the fixed code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

s = pd.Series([random.randint(0, 20) for x in range(0, 10)], index=list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
print(s.value_counts())
print(s.sum())
```

Comment: This actually is not a problem in python, as long as there are open parentheses.